# Django can't load javascript but load css (include link to project)

Tags: javascript, python, django

Please your help.. I spent hours to understand it

I started a very basic template with Django, and it **can't find my js files, while it can find the css file** - when both of them in static folder

[Here is a link for the project (1.4MB)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OxYmp-sACIN71bkEKtA69HOZgXEEus2n?usp=sharing)

Thanks a lot!

```
[11/Jun/2020 00:21:18] "GET /js/init.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2134
Not Found: /js/materialize.js
[11/Jun/2020 00:21:18] "GET /js/materialize.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2155
Not Found: /js/init.js
```

**In Setting.py I have these settings:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
```

**My Page index.html:**
[image: HTML part]

**This is my Project Dictionary:**
3 folders - (1) home [the app] (2) project_folder (3) static - contain css, js, images

[image]

Comment: have you configured in `urls.py`?

Comment: And I think forgot to end `STATICFILES_DIRS` list

Comment: @PruthviBarot
app **urls.py** configured:
`urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='index'),`

**Views.py:**
`def home(request):`
    `return render(request, 'index.html')`

I have the end ] in the file

Any other idea?  the rest looks fine?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Obviously it was a small mistake that messed with the whole thing:

Even though I've added the JS at the top correctly like this:

```
<head>
   ...
 <!-- JS  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=11SXwFQpXEPJB6y_0aExroDW6VD97egRb"></script>
</head>
```

I had this code at the end of the HTML:

```
  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Fixed by:

1. removing the JS from the top of the page completely
2. editing the SCRIPTS at the bottom like the below:

[image]